Google Cloud calendar API connection error
I am developing a web application in which you can see your calendar from your Google account.
My calendar is inside an iframe within the main page (index.html) and is activated when pressing a button
When from the index.html I press the button that loads the Google calendar in the iframe I get this error twice in the console: Error signing in to Google: Error: The Google API has not been loaded correctly.
at showGoogleCalendar (calendar2/:119:12)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (calendar2/:245:62)
showCalendarGoogle @ calendar2/:145
onclick @calendar2/:245 in these lines:

Calendario2/:145
(is the showGoogleCalendar() function)

Calendario2/:178
(is the handleError() function)


On the google cloud platform I have the Google Calendar API enabled, I have my api key, my OAuth 2.0 client ID and the redirect URL configured.
EDIT: I solved this problem thanks to Twilight's comment

I am not fully familiar with the flow of your project but  have you also checked if you have included the necessary dependencies for Google API  and scopes? or You may also refer to this quick start or retry to rerun the project.

@Twilight Yes!, I was looking at that quick start guide a long time ago, but like in the rest of the app I use fullcalendar, my idea was to press the button in the index where it would ask me for the login/authorization and the iframe would load with it. calendar and events, I will continue testing with the test code anyway to see what I can reuse from there

@Twilight Hello again, I have been testing with the Google code and the truth is that I have made a lot of progress, it now loads everything correctly and the events, I am missing two things to have perfect functioning and I suppose I will reedit the question to focus on those two problems

I am glad that I have answered your initial question, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.

I would like to post my comment as an answer so that we can help other people with the same issue. If it was useful to you, feel free to upvote/accept it.

As per my suggestion in the comment section, posting it as an answer:
The concern has been addressed thru double checking necessary Google API dependencies and scopes. Additionally, referring to this Javascript Quickstart(Calendar API).
